# jQuery fade-in text wraps at first then squishes up during transition

Tags: jquery

Sorry, I know it's not a great Title description but the effect is difficult to describe and sort of needs to be observed.  See the jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/eus5R/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var speed = 2500;
        $("div#leftPane p").hide();

        $("div#leftPane").click(function() {
            $("div#leftPane p").each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
                    $(this).show(speed);
                    exit();
                }
            });                           
        });
    });
```

Basically, I have a bunch of p's that start hidden and I want to reveal one at a time by mouse click.  I want the reveal to take a half-second, fading the text in.  The problem is that during the fade-in transition, the text juggles around as the browser tries to render it properly.  How can I avoid that "juggling" and just have it fade-in already rendered as it will finally be shown?

Thanks!

Comment: @JamesMontagne well, an effective way to stop the loop :)

Comment: Doh!  Thanks guys, I always embarrass myself on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `show` with a duration animates the width as well.  The smaller width causes the text to wrap. You can use `slideDown` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/eus5R/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `show` and `hide` use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var speed = 2500;
            $("div#leftPane p").fadeOut(0);

            $("div#leftPane").click(function() {
                $("div#leftPane p").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
                        $(this).fadeIn(speed);
                        return false;
                    }
                });                           
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eus5R/2/

Oh and instead of non-existant `exit()` which breaks the `each` because it throws an exception, do a `return false`

Comment: Hah, who knew?! (obviously everyone).  Thanks for the fadeIn/Out and the note on my non-existing-function.